# history.pushState : send a POST parameters

Tags: post, pushstate

I want to pass a POST parameter but can not find the solution. I tried this but without success

```
url = '?page=test',
title = 'Africa';

var options = {

        type: 'POST',
        data: {test:'1'} 

    };

history.pushState({options: options, url: url, title: title }, title, url);
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thank you